# How do I know in which Polkadot release a Substrate PR (hence change) got in?

Tags: polkadot, releases

I am trying to figure out in which Polkadot release the `Deposit` and `Withdraw` events were introduced.

I was looking at the corresponding PR, [Add Deposit and Withdraw Events to Balances Pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/9425) in the [Substrate repo](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate) and it looks like it was merged on Oct 11th, 2021.

So then I was checking in the [Polkadot repo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot) the releases by date and the first one after Oct 11th, 2021 was the [release v0.9.12](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.12) on Oct 21, 2021. So my assumption is that this change got in the release v0.9.12.

Is there another way to check the same ?

Answer (score 4):

We can also go to the [Substrate repo](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate) and from the dropdown box that mentions all the existing branches

[image: substrate choose branch screenshot]

choose the  branch that corresponds to polkadot releases, e.g. branch `polkadot-v0.9.10` or `polkadot-v0.9.21`. It is a somehow manual way but if we know approximately the date that the PR was merged then we can check only the releases close to that date.
Whenever we choose the branch of a specific release, we can then look all the commits of this branch/release.

If the merged commit (or we can also search by the PR description) we are looking for is present then it means it was introduced in that release.

[image: substrate repo - PR found in commits of release]

Thank you Iker, Alejandro, Alex & Bruno for the help & feedback on this one!

Answer (score 1):

A cool and easy way of checking whether a commit is in which branches is by using the command

`git branch --contains <commit>`

This will prompt your **local branches** where the specified commit is present. Take into account that this will only check for you the branches fetched locally.